# "systemctl status apache2" Failed to start the Apache HTTP Server

Tags: lubuntu, apache2, php, lamp

I'm using Ubuntu and I wanted to install apache2 so I could use php.

I followed the instructions in this website:

https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Here is the error I get.

```
    root@DSK0977:/var/www/html/phpmonitor.com/logs# sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-04-17 09:04:44 WEST; 14min ago
  Process: 906 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

abr 17 09:04:43 DSK0977 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
abr 17 09:04:43 DSK0977 apachectl[906]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 25 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmonitor.com.conf:
abr 17 09:04:43 DSK0977 apachectl[906]: CustomLog takes two or three arguments, a file name, a custom log format string or format name, and an optional "env=" or "expr=" clause (see docs)
abr 17 09:04:43 DSK0977 apachectl[906]: Action 'start' failed.
abr 17 09:04:43 DSK0977 apachectl[906]: The Apache error log may have more information.
abr 17 09:04:44 DSK0977 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
abr 17 09:04:44 DSK0977 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
abr 17 09:04:44 DSK0977 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Here is the file with the error which I had I forgot to put:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/phpmonitor.com/public_html>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpmonitor.com/public_html

        ErrorLog /var/www/html/phpmonitor.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/html/phpmonitor.com/logs/access.log combined #This is line 25, I've removed the comments

</VirtualHost>
```

PS: if you wish to help and need information just ask, I'm in the last hour of work after bumping heads with a ton of errors, and I probably didn't put in allot of important information.

Comment: Please add line 25 of the file `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/phpmonitor.com.conf` to your question. According to the error message in contains an error.

Comment: I've added the whole file, it isn't very long if it doensn't have comments.

Answer (score 0):

Don't post images of text. Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1134426/edit ) your post, copy-and-paste your text, select it, and choose the `{}` formatting tool.

Second, Read your error messages! They tell you that there's a syntax error on line 25 of a file, and hint at the correction.

Third, Read your logs. Inspect `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for more information.

Fourth, read about the "CustomLog" command at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't put the file that had the error in it, it's there now. Also the error log was empty.